# C# For Loop with Random Int Generator locks the program

Tags: c#, loops, random

I have 2 one dimensional arrays, containing the exact same values:

```
public int[] start = new int[21] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14 };

public int[] end = new int[21] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14 };
```

Below is the code I use to generate a random index, and grab the element from the array with said index, and stick it in a 2D array, with randomly generated X and Y index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            Random ranNum = new Random();
            int genX = 0;
            int genY = 5;
            int indx = 1;

            while (gameBoard[genX, genY].rank > -1)
            {
                genX = ranNum.Next(0, 9);
                genY = ranNum.Next(5, 8);
            }
            while (start[indx] == -1)
            {
                indx = ranNum.Next(0, 21);
            }
            if (gameBoard[genX, genY].rank == -1)
            {
                gameBoard[genX, genY].rank = start[indx];
                start[indx] = -1;
            }
            while (gameBoard[genX, genY].rank > -1)
            {
                genX = ranNum.Next(0, 9);
                genY = ranNum.Next(0, 3);
            }
            while (end[indx] == -1)
            {
                indx = ranNum.Next(0, 21);
            }
            if (gameBoard[genX, genY].rank == -1)
            {
                gameBoard[genX, genY].rank = end[indx];
                end[indx] = -1;
            }                
        }
```

Basically, it takes a value from the "start" and "end" arrays, replaces them with a '-1' (so they don't get picked again), scans the 2D array for '-1s' (so it doesn't place the number in a location that already has one), and places it there.

Notice that the min and max value for the random are different for the "start" and "end" arrays. This is to ensure that they end up far away from each other, on the other side of the 2D array.

This code works. Now, I have a code that resets all the variables back to their previous state. A reset function which also works. See, if the user is not content with the random placement, they can reset the arrays, and randomize again.

At which point the program simply hangs / locks up. No error, no messages, it just stops working. Please, could you share any ideas on how / why this happens?

Note: If I remove the entire while loop concerning the "end" array, the program can randomize and reset all it wants.

Anyway, the code for the reset:

```
int resVal = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            {
                startBoard[i] = resVal;
                enemyBoard[i] = resVal;
                if (i == 0)
                    resVal++;
                else if (i >= 6 && i < 19)
                    resVal++;
            }

for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
                {
                    gameBoard[x, y] = new classPiece();
                    gameBoard[x, y].rank = -1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should reuse the `Random` instance.

Comment: If it hangs when the reset function fires, perhaps you should also post the code for that so we can see what its doing?

Comment: "To improve performance, create one Random to generate many random numbers over time, instead of repeatedly creating a new Random to generate one random number." - Quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: are you sure that end[] doesn't contain only -1 after reset or something else?

Comment: Rewrote the code to make less use of the Random statement. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `Random ranNum = new Random();` out of the cycle.